# How can I make an iPad app to start over everytime I close it?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I'm making a multiple choice iPad app, where after 5 questions you need to start over. The problem is that I did it with `UIViewControllers`, so when I want to go back to the menu with a simple button, the app gets stuck... How do I make the app reload every time I finish the questions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have an app delegate controlling your view controllers?  If so, you can put in code to simulate a restart in the main app delegate...

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
     // any code to simulate a restart
}
```

Comment: This is only called when the application comes out of the background.